# Cannot reinstall grub on newly created boot partitiion

Tags: centos6, grub

```
12. Reinstall grub on the newly boot partition:
# grub-install --recheck /dev/xvdg
# sed -i 's/sdg/xvdg/g' /boot/grub/device.map
# grub-install /dev/xvdg
```

Running first line gives:

```
Probing devices to guess BIOS drives. This may take a long time.
No suitable drive was found in the generated device map.
Reverting to backed up copy.
```

It seems to create device.map, so I continue, the second command works, but the third gives me:

```
expr: non-numeric argument
Could not find device for /boot
```

lblsk gives me:

```
[root@ip-111-111-111-111 grub]# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM    SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0      8G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0      8G  0 part 
xvdf    202:80   0      2T  0 disk 
└─xvdf1 202:81   0    1.6T  0 part 
xvdg    202:96   0      1G  0 disk 
└─xvdg1 202:97   0 1019.7M  0 part /boot
```

Comment: i would use wipefs and recreate the filesystem with ext2/3/4 depending what you use

Comment: any tutorial or resource for doing this?

Comment: wipefs and mkfs should be known. So this interprets me that you are an Enduser which makes the question off topic. Superuser.com have to be used for this kind of question. Personally i would only split the boot partition only if its a non usually bootable FS for grub, but zfs as example doesn't need this